# Unknown (maybe user input) segfault NASM 32-bit?

Tags: assembly, segmentation-fault, printf, nasm, 32-bit

I'm getting a segfault but I'm having a hard time locating the reason. The command line isn't giving me any warnings or errors and my build commands are:

> ```
> nasm -f elf32 filename.asm -o test.o
> gcc test.o 
> ./a.out T22000129/ ;this input is suppose to give 3
> ```

My whole code is :

```
   global  main
   extern  printf

    section .text
    
    main:
    mov     eax, [esp+4]            
    mov     eax, [esp+8]           
    mov ebx, [eax+4] ;these 3 are to get the input and they might be the problem I'm not sure
    
    
    mov ecx,0 ;this will be my index
    call checksum
    push eax
    push stringFormat
    call printf

    checksum:
    mov al,[ebx] ;getting a byte of input
    movzx eax,al
    cmp eax,47 ;comparing to the end char "/" if yes go to done
    je done
    add ebx,1 ;moving the input
    call convert
    imul dword[factor+ecx*4]
    add [sum], eax
    inc ecx
    call checksum
    ret


   done:    
    mov eax,[sum]
    mov ecx,10
    xor edx,edx
    div ecx
    mov eax,edx
    ret

   convert:
    cmp eax,60 
    jg letter   
    jl number

   flag:
    ret 

   letter: 
    sub eax,55
    jmp flag 

    number:
     sub eax,48
     jmp flag

    section .data

    stringFormat:
            db  '"%s%1d"', 10, 0
     factor: dd 7,3,1,7,3,1,7,3,1
     sum: dd 0`
```

It might look a bit complicated. The general structure is: I get an input string from the user, check it byte by byte, if it's a number subtract 48 and if a letter subtract 55. Then after subtracting I return to multiply with my factors and adding it to the sum. When I reach the end character "/" I read 47 and jump to done. Get the last digit of the sum and return that.

**EDIT**: I replaced `stringFormat: db  '"%s%1d"', 10, 0` with `decNumFormat: db '"%d"', 10, 0` which fixed the situation but I have no idea why that was causing the problem.

Comment: Well, why did you put a `%s` format specifier in your format string in the first place? As far as I can tell you just want to format an integer.

Comment: that part was from the base code our instructor gave and just said to use it, so I didn't question it but I see the issue now, thank you.

Comment: Maybe your instructor wanted you to pass a pointer to the input string as the first arg after the format string, so the output was `.../3` instead of just `3`.  It is a checksum / check-digit calculation after all.